# Schedule repeating org-agenda TODO entry with diary sexp and time

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, diary

I have repeating appointments for the next half year and want them to show up in my agenda. I managed to make them show on the correct dates like this:

```
* TODO Example Event
SCHEDULED: <%%(and(diary-block 10 15 2023 4 11 2024)(= 5 (calendar-day-of-week date)))>
```

I would like to also schedule the event at a specific time during the day like you normally would with simple time stamps eg. `SCHEDULED: <2023-10-16 15:00>`.
If i simply add the time after the sexp like this:

```
* TODO Example Event
SCHEDULED: <%%(and(diary-block 10 15 2023 4 11 2024)(= 5 (calendar-day-of-week date))) 15:00>
```

they are no longer recognized as a scheduled TODO entry.

I'm sure there is a way to do what I want, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do that: diary sexps are supported by Org mode, but with limitations and I believe this is one of them: you cannot specify the time. You could do just a normal Org mode repeating date (`SCHEDULED: <2023-10-16 Mon 15:00 +1w>`) but you cannot specify a termination date; you would have to get rid of the repeater manually at the appropriate time. Or you could use `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` to add a number of occurrences.

Comment: @NickD I did it with normal repeating dates until now but I thought there would be a nicer way... 
I have to look in to `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` i didn't hear of that before, thanks for the recommendation.